# openCV says it cannot find the camera

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

hello everyone im triying to use my camera to get videos using openCV and Visual studio 2012 (C++) but an error message appears : "no camera detected !!!"
 the pictures explain my probleme :

whene i execute my code :

[image]

i chose Ok :

[image]

My code :

```
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>


#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;



int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    CvCapture* capture = 0;
    Mat frame, frameCopy, image;


    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY ); //0=default, -1=any camera, 1..99=your camera

if( !capture )
{
cout << "No camera detected" << endl;
system("pause");
}

cvNamedWindow( "result", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

if( capture )
{
cout << "In capture ..." << endl;
for(;;)
{
IplImage* iplImg = cvQueryFrame( capture );
frame = iplImg;

if( frame.empty() )
break;
if( iplImg->origin == IPL_ORIGIN_TL )
frame.copyTo( frameCopy );
else
flip( frame, frameCopy, 0 );

cvShowImage( "result", iplImg );

if( waitKey( 10 ) >= 0 )
break;
}
// waitKey(0);
}



cvWaitKey(50);

cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvDestroyWindow( "result" );

return 0;
    }
```

Thanks for advance

Comment: What video/camera backends do you have compiled with your distribution of OpenCV? Eg, ffmpeg/gstreamer? Also, what version of OpenCV?

Comment: it's openCV2.2 ,ffmpeg/gstreamer ???!!! sorry i don't understand

Comment: OpenCV doesn't actually contain any code to talk to your camera. It wraps 3rd party libraries which know how to talk to cameras. If it wasn't compiled with a backend that's also installed on your system, it won't be able to open any cameras. Two such libraries that OpenCV can be configured (at build time) to use are ffmpeg and gstreamer.

Comment: i use ffmpeg library :: opencv_ffmpeg220d.lib

Comment: It's a common problem with VFW (video for windows) - thats the VFW camera selection dialog. It's common for apps that use the subsystem to work the first time around, but fail on subsequent executions. Rebooting fixes the problem - provided the camera works in the first place. The (only) other way I've found is to run a Flash script that uses the camera. I've been trying to get an answer as to what it is that I'm not shutting-down or re-initializing properly for over a year now. Good luck, sorry I can't really help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is not nothing wrong with your code. check your webcam again. (for example, webcam driver ), and test : `"capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( -1 );"`